Java doesn't use JIRA credentials
So I have a pom.xml file that generates a jar file through the command mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -DJIRA_USER='...' -DJIRA_PASS='...'. When i then run java -jar -DJIRA_USER='...' -DJIRA_PASS='...' target\dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 'RG Desktop 1.21.0' I get the following:

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2024-04-08 16:47:00.652  INFO 8668 --- [           main] com.wkfsfrc.dita.DitaApplication         : Starting DitaApplication v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on BE84DXGL4427TN with PID 8668 (C:\dita\DITA-Utility\target\dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by in C:\Users\dita\DITA-Utility)
2024-04-08 16:47:00.654  INFO 8668 --- [           main] com.wkfsfrc.dita.DitaApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2024-04-08 16:47:01.287  INFO 8668 --- [           main] com.wkfsfrc.dita.DitaApplication         : Started DitaApplication in 0.995 seconds (JVM running for 1.318)
Calling dita app...
Connecting Jira to fetch the data of release = RG Desktop 1.21.0
https://jira.wolterskluwer.io
2024-04-08 16:47:02.743  INFO 8668 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-08 16:47:02.743 ERROR 8668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:773) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.wkfsfrc.dita.DitaApplication.main(DitaApplication.java:21) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) ~[dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) ~[dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[dita-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(401), errorCollections=[]}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:328) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:315) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:113) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.get(DelegatingPromise.java:102) ~[jira-rest-java-client-core-4.0.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.wkfsfrc.dita.service.AbstractDitaService.generateReleaseNotes(AbstractDitaService.java:85) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wkfsfrc.dita.controller.ReleaseNoteController.generateReleaseNoteData(ReleaseNoteController.java:35) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wkfsfrc.dita.DitaApplication.run(DitaApplication.java:26) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 12 of










<html>

<head>
    <title>Unauthorized (401)</title>







<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var contextPath = '/jira';

        function printDeprecatedMsg() {
            if (console && console.warn) {
                console.warn('DEPRECATED JS - contextPath global variable has been deprecated since 7.4.0. Use `wrm/context-path` module instead.');

Does someone know how I can pass the JIRA USER and PASS also to the jar installation so the authentication works?
I tried installing the jar without the credentials but of course that doesn't work too.

Hi Robbe, Welcome to SO and congratulations on your first post. The question doesn't have adequate information in it to attract community response. For example, what is the DITA application. Is it your source code? Why is there HTML content in the post? is it printed in the logs?

The dita application generates Release Notes of the company i do my internship (code is theirs). The HTML response is a HTML of the jira page that says it is unauthorized. That is the problem I need to solve. I can set variables for the maven clean install but when installing the jar it doesn't take the credentials and it is not authorized.

Without the source code it is not possible to troubleshoot what kind of api call is being made to jira. Jira seems to be returning a html response instead of a json, which is why you see restclientexception. It is most likely that you have bad credentials
